# one-to-one mapping using unique constraint not working as expected

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying this simple uni-directional one-to-one relationship

Person ----> Address

using many-to-one mapping with unique constraint.

This is how my mapping looks like in Person.hbm.xml:

```
<class name="Person" table="PERSON">
<many-to-one name="address" column="ADDRESS_ID" cascade="all" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
```

I think this should allow only one unique Address per Person - no two Persons can share a common address.

So, the following code should fail. But in this code Hibernate allows both the Johns to stay at same address.

```
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    Address address = new Address("Bond Street", "London", 121212);
    Person person1 = new Person("John Doe", address);
    Person person2 = new Person("John McClane", address);
    session.save(person1);
    session.save(person2);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
```

Please let me know what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you added the unique constraint in your database schema?

Comment: No.. :-0 but wondering where does Hibernate's unique="true" helps if it'll depend on the schema constraint itself? Then is unique="true" just a marker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e7576, and find the many-to-one description in paragraph 5.1.7.1. It says :

> unique (optional): enables the DDL
>   generation of a unique constraint for
>   the foreign-key column. By allowing
>   this to be the target of a
>   property-ref, you can make the
>   association multiplicity one-to-one.

This means that it's used by the database schema generation tool of Hibernate to add a unique constraint. If you don't use it, then you must add this constraint yourself.

Comment: ah thanks!! if we are not using hibernate to create DDLs for us, we should add the constraints ourselves.. got it.. (I think not-null attribute is also related but slightly different as it does runtime checks as well)